# Removing the black bar between divs and having them share a background image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a weather website. In the body I have a div for my search bar, and then a div below it for the main area with the weather information. The problem is that there is a divider between the two (below the search area and above the main area) How do I get rid of this? I have tried margins but I can't figure out what I'm missing.

As well, I am trying to get these two divs to share one background image

Thanks in advance

```
<div class="searchArea">
  <ul>
  <li><div><input type="text" id="search_term" placeholder="Other Location ..."></div></li>
  <li><div><input type="submit" value="Check Weather" onclick="findNewWeather()" /></div></li>    
  </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="mainArea">
    <h1>City Name</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div>
                <h1>Current</h1>
                <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/10d@2x.png" alt="today icon">
                <h2>12oC</h2>
                <h3>Feels: 9oC</h3>
                <h3>Mostly Sunny</h3>

ETC ....
```

```
.weatherMain {
  margin-top: 1px;
  background-image: url("./WP.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: gray;
  padding: 25px0px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 600px;
  font-family: poiret one;
  font-size: 35px;
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.searchArea {
  background-image: url("./banff.jpg");
  background-position: 0 -75;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 1):

Given the code you posted above, I think the problem is that your `<ul>` and `<h1>` tags have their own margins that are pushing your `<div>` tags apart.

This should fix the issue:

```css
.searchArea ul {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.weatherMain h1 { /* or .mainArea h1, your example has both */
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

To give them one background, I would recommend wrapping them in a `<div>` and applying the background image to that.